# MongoDB error on meanjs running in windows 7

Tags: mongodb, meanjs

Error on mongoDb while running meanJs, When i am trying to run the MeanJs its showing database error. But the mongo server is showing up

I am using windows7, Please check the screenshot attached of error. Please let me know the issue of this error ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error has been resolved.

The host is the issue of this MongoError.

Instead of using `localhost:27017` Use the ip address that is showing, while running the mongod.exe . i am used the id address to solve the mongoerror is `http://127.0.0.1:27017/`

If the db is active then we can see a page of mongodb is like :[image]